# MAAS nodes ready but showing 0 cpu-count and 0 memory

Tags: maas

I have a MAAS private cloud using IBM xserver 3550/3650's. The Cluster controller was set up with Ubuntu server 12.10 and 6 nodes were PXE booted using MAAS default options. My problem is that all nodes show up in ready state but showing 0 cpu-count and 0 MB memory (in reality all nodes have 2 Xeon 5140 processors and 5 or 6 MB memory) and when I try to bootstrap juju I get a "No matching node is available" error. Does anyone have an idea what my problem is and/or how I can configure the nodes correctly in MAAS.

Hjortur

Answer (score 2):

Can you run 'lshw -xml' and include the output on a bug report on Launchpad?
We had a problem with some systems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1064638
Essentially, the detection of memory sometimes fails when we get a setup we haven't seen before.

If you can open a new bug and include the lshw content, we should be able to properly detect your memory.

I think you can deploy with juju using '--constraints "mem=0 cpu=0"'.